# JavaScript average calculator

Tags: javascript, average, calculator

I am wondering how i would make a function that will record the 10 most recent Date.now commands and then turn them into an average. I then want to put it into a side bar and make it sort of like a scoreboard. http://jsfiddle.net/eh5dxyp4/ . Thanks in advance

```
  clickedTime=Date.now();

  reactionTime=(clickedTime-createdTime)/1000;

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=reactionTime;

  this.style.display="none";

  makeBox();

 }

 makeBox();`
```

Comment: Could you make this a jsfiddle.net. Also removing some of the blank lines might help

Answer (score 1):

You've shown quite a bit of code that doesn't seem relevant to the actual maths part of your question. I'm going to provide one way to do this part:

> *record the 10 most recent Date.now commands and then turn them into an average*

Create an array:

```
var recent = [];
```

And a function that adds a value to that array but also ensures there will only be at most ten items in it:

```
var recentLimit = 10;
function addRecentItem(item) {
    recent.push(item); // add to end of array
    if (recent.length > recentLimit)
       recent.shift(); // remove from start of array
}
```

Then you just need a function to calculate the average:

```
function getRecentAverage() {
    var i,
        sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < recent.length; i++)
        sum += recent[i];
    return sum / recent.length;
}
```

So then wherever in your code you produce one of the `Date.now` objects you can simply add it to the `recent` list:

```
addRecentItem(yourValueHere);
```

And then get the current average:

```
console.log( getRecentAverage() );
```

As far as your scoreboard concept goes, you just need a function that loops through whatever is in the `recent` array and creates appropriate html elements (li elements, for example).

Comment: Hi nnnnnnn thanks for the answer but i still dont understand how i can use your code to average out the latest 10 reaction times, when ever i look at the javascript log in chrome it records every reaction time not just the latest 10. Im fairly new to javascipt so im sorry if im getting it wrong. thanks.

Comment: Hi. No, my code only keeps the last 10 values that were passed to my `addRecentItem()` function. I did test it before posting, but I'm not sure how you're using it...

Answer (score 0):

Add    `var reactionTimes=[];` somewhere outside the function that calulates it then use

```
var reactionTime = (clickedTime-createdTime)/1000;
reactionTimes.push(reactionTime);
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=reactionTime;
if (reactionTimes.length==10) {
  var average = reactionTimes.reduce(function(sum, a) { return sum + a },0)/(reactionTimes.length!=0?reactionTimes.length:1);
  reactionTimes.pop(); // make ready for a new 10th value
  document.getElementById("average").innerHTML=average;
}
```